# how to repeat sound using sleep method

Tags: java, audio, methods, sleep, repeat

i have a problem repeating a sound after clicking a button but its keep repeating until i click the stop button, i want to repeat it using sleep method but it says "the method sleep is undefined for the type onclicklistener() "

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);

        for(int i=0;i<3;++i)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<1;++j)
            {
                mp.start();
                sleep(2);
            }
            sleep(5);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks like you on Android, java. Perhaps provide proper tags.

Comment: This isn't a good way to loop audio for so many reasons. If you are using android.media.MediaPlayer, [according to the doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setLooping%28boolean%29) it supports looping on its own.

Answer (score 0):

`sleep()` is a method of `Thread` class, so you can say `Thread.sleep(2000)` to sleep for two seconds, for example. Since this throws `InterruptedException`, you will also need to catch that.